# Checkbox incorrectly saved as 'array'

Tags: php, yii

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <input id="ytAdd_Employee_varHobbies" type="hidden" value="" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies]">
      <span id="Add_Employee_varHobbies">
      <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_0" value="5" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
      <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_0">BaseBall</label>
      <br>
      <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_1" value="2" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
      <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_1">Football</label>
      <br>
      <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_2" value="4" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
      <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_2">Hockey</label>
      <br></div>
```

Here I have multiple checkboxes as array in the name of Add_Employee[varHobbies][]

In the controller I saved the form as

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Add_Employee'];
     //print_r($model);exit;
     $image_upload=$model->Image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'Image'); 

     if( $model->validate() && $model->save())
     {  }
```

By using $model->save() all my fields are saved properly but this checkbox saved as array.

In my model I set the rules as

```
array('varHobbies', 'type', 'type' => 'array', 'allowEmpty' => false),
```

I want to save the hobbies as 1,2,3 and so on....

But it is saved as 'array'.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more related to your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your model to save hobbies as a string:

```
protected function beforeSave() {
parent::beforeSave();
$this->varHobbies = implode(',', $this->varHobbies);
return $this;
}
```